# Store callback in the object

Tags: javascript

Can we store callback function in a Object and then after call callback by retrieving from object.

```
var myArray = [];

function myFoo(myCallback)
{
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.call_back = myCallback; // Store in object 

    myArray.push(obj); // Add in array
}

function doSomething(results)
{
    for(var index=0;index < myArray.length;index++)
    {
        var obj = myArray[index];
        if( obj.hasOwnProperty("call_back") )
        {
            var callbackMethod = obj.call_back;
            callbackMethod(results); // Call callback
        }
    }
}
```

Is it valid to implement?

Comment: Yep, You can do that

Comment: Yes. It is possible

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: Yes, you can do so. However, it is better to also test for `typeof obj.call_back === 'function'` prior to actually trying to execute it.

Comment: `var obj = new Object();` *Cringe*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is valid. But do you want to store more information in those objects or just the callbacks? If only callbacks you can just store them as is in the array

```
var myCallbacks = [];

function myFoo(myCallback) {
  myCallbacks.push(myCallback);
}

function doSomething(results) {
  var index;

  for(index = 0; index < myCallbakcs.length; index++) {
    myCallbacks[index]();
  }
}
```